# Why does the extending of string type work and map to readonly?

Tags: typescript

I am currently working on a few typescript challenges to improve, one of those was to implement a DeepReadOnly type. I didn't succeed initially and looked up the answers. One of those answers was:

```typescript
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? T[P] : DeepReadonly<T[P]>
}
```

The **test case** was as follows:

```typescript
type X = {
  a: () => 22
  b: string
  c: {
    d: boolean
    e: {
      g: {
        h: {
          i: true
          j: 'string'
        }
        k: 'hello'
      }
    }
  }
}

type Expected = {
  readonly a: () => 22
  readonly b: string
  readonly c: {
    readonly d: boolean
    readonly e: {
      readonly g: {
        readonly h: {
          readonly i: true
          readonly j: 'string'
        }
        readonly k: 'hello'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My specific question is why this works on `X['b']` which is of type `string`? `T[P] extends Function` should be false from what I understand?

Comment: Is your question why `DeepReadonly<string>` is the same as `string`? Or why `DeepReadonly<string>` isn't some kind of error?

Comment: Both to be honest :)

Comment: Fair enough. :-) Keep in mind that `keyof string` does result in things (`number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" |`...). `string[number]` is already `readonly`. But I suspect that isn't what's going on, not least because [it doesn't make those functions readonly](https://tsplay.dev/mA79Bw). I suspect a mapped type on a primitive type just results in the primitive type, unchanged, but I can't find that written down anywhere in a ...

Comment: ...few minutes of trying. I suspect that in part because of this quote from Anders Hejlsberg: [*"It generally isn't meaningful to apply mapped types to primitives..."*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13351#issuecomment-271160256)

Comment: I understand that the mapped type on a primitive type results in the primitive type, unchanged, but it still confuses me, especially because of the constraint.

Comment: What constraint?

Comment: Each property is mapped to a conditional type, as defined by `DeepReadonly`. In particular, `X[b]` is not a function, so it is mapped to `DeepReadonly<X[b]>`,
which means `DeepReadonly<string>`

Now the recursion ends - you have a primitive type as an argument to mapped type, which maps to a primitive.

Comment: Great, I understand now :) Thanks alot, y'all